# Need help debugging why property is not set/null

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a class `WorkQueue`, just take note about the `DoNext()` for now, the rest are mainly helpers. Basically, `WorkQueue` is just a Queue of `WorkItems`. `DoNext()` is responsible for "Starting a Pending WorkItem with a Free Background Worker". Also note that it will set the `WorkItem.Worker` property.

```
public class WorkQueue<Tin, Tout> :
    INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<WorkItem<Tin, Tout>>
{
    public bool DoNext()
    {
        // check if any work left in queue
        WorkItem<Tin, Tout> item = GetWork();
        if (item != null)
        {
            // check if any free workers
            BackgroundWorker worker = GetWorker();
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "[WorkQueue.DoNext] Setting Worker to WorkItem: " + worker);
            item.Worker = worker;
            if (worker != null)
            {
                worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void AddWork(WorkItem<Tin, Tout> item)
    {
        _queue.Add(item);
        RaiseCollectionChanged(
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }

    public WorkItem<Tin, Tout> GetWork()
    {
        return (from i in _queue
                where i.Status == WorkStatus.Pending
                select i).FirstOrDefault();;
    }

    public BackgroundWorker GetWorker()
    {
        return (from worker in _workers
                where worker.IsBusy == false
                select worker).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when I do something like below,

```
foreach (string filename in fileNames) {
    UploadQueue.AddWork(new WorkItem<string, UploadedImage>(filename));
    UploadQueue.DoNext();
}
```

Where `UploadQueue` is a `WorkQueue<string, UploadedImage>`. On the 1st (first only) `DoNext()`, the `WorkItem.Worker` is null. I know that because my Cancel button bound to `WorkItem.CancelCommand` is disabled. When debugging, I discovered the reason was because worker is null.

```
_cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(... () =>
{
    // Returns true if WorkItem is being processed with a worker that supports
    // cancellation or if the WorkItem is still Pending
    // False if otherwise, eg. already completed, cancelled etc
    if (Status == WorkStatus.Processing)
    {
        if (_worker != null && _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
            return true;
    } else if (Status == WorkStatus.Pending) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The solution is to move the `DoNext()` out of the loop,

```
foreach (string filename in fileNames)
    UploadQueue.AddWork(new WorkItem<string, UploadedImage>(filename));
UploadQueue.DoNext();
```

but whats the problem with it inside, why is worker set to null? If its null, from the if clause, the `BackgroundWorker` should not start?

```
if (worker != null)
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
```

[Video Demonstrating the Problem](http://screenr.com/akF)

Comment: that's not how I would use background workers...

Comment: When is the check for the button status? And where does the _cancelCommand fit in?

Comment: Just a suggestion, have you thought about using Tasks instead?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I thought it is very messy too. This implementation. Care to elaborate what am I ding wrong? Maybe I should be using Progress & RunWorkerCompleted call backs instead of properties of `WorkItem`?

Comment: @Doggett, the check for button status in in the 2nd callback in my RelayCommand declaration http://pastebin.com/U0f3eYFj. `CancelCommand` simply calls `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()`

Comment: @Paw Baltzersen, I thought of that, but can I track progress? Or maybe I need to hack my way using something like [this](http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3395379/Tracking-Progress-Multi-Step-Task)?

Comment: @jiewmeng, it's doable with a few tricks as in the link you posted. Do you need to support cancelation? If so you also need to implement this with a cancelation token. Tasks might not be the best solution for you, but it could help you handle more work items in less time. Just queue em all up and let the tasking framework take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public BackgroundWorker GetWorker()
{
    return (from worker in _workers
            where worker.IsBusy == false
            select worker).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

if all of the workers are busy, this function will return null;

```
foreach (string filename in fileNames)
    UploadQueue.AddWork(new WorkItem<string, UploadedImage>(filename));
    UploadQueue.DoNext();
```

UploadQueue.DoNext() executed multiple times

```
foreach (string filename in fileNames)
    UploadQueue.AddWork(new WorkItem<string, UploadedImage>(filename));
UploadQueue.DoNext();
```

UploadQueue.DoNext() executed once.

Then it's quite clear, if you execute UploadQueue.DoNext() multiple times in a short time period, there will be no worker which is not busy, so you get a null worker